# Generic Matrix Class conversions between different numbers

Tags: java, generics

so I have to create a Matrix class that will generically combine different objects in an array. I know I can do this by checking the types but I want to find a better way. This has to work on Doubles, Integers, Floats, Shorts, Longs, Strings, etc. Here is my current code for this:

```
public class Matrix<E>{



private E mat2[];
private static final int SIZE = 4;



public Matrix(){
    mat2 = (E[]) new Object[SIZE];
}

public Matrix(E a1, E a2, E b1, E b2){
    mat2 = (E[]) new Object[SIZE];
    mat2[0] = a1;
    mat2[1] = a2;
    mat2[2] = b1;
    mat2[3] = b2;
}


public void add(Matrix<E> info){
    if(mat2[0] instanceof Number){
        for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
            Double tmp = ((Double)info.getElement(i)).doubleValue();
            Double other = tmp + ((Double)mat2[i]).doubleValue();
            mat2[i] = (E) other;
        }
    }
}

public E getElement(int index){ return mat2[index];}


public String toString(){
    String info = "[";
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        info += "\t" + mat2[i];
        info += (i % 2 == 1) ? "\t]\n[" : "";
    }
    return info.substring(0, info.length() - 1);
}



public static void main(String... arg){

    Matrix<Integer> matInt = new Matrix<Integer>(new Integer(1), new Integer(0), new Integer(0), new Integer(1));
    Matrix<Integer> matInt2 = new Matrix<Integer>(new Integer(1), new Integer(0), new Integer(0), new Integer(1));
    System.out.println(matInt);


    Matrix<String> matStr = new Matrix<String>("One", "Two", "Three", "Four");
    System.out.println(matStr);

    matInt.add(matInt2);
    System.out.println(matInt);



}
```

}

Now let me draw your attention to this method:

```
public void add(Matrix<E> info){
    if(mat2[0] instanceof Number){
        for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
            Double tmp = ((Double)info.getElement(i)).doubleValue();
            Double other = tmp + ((Double)mat2[i]).doubleValue();
            mat2[i] = (E) other;
        }
    }
}
```

I am assuming Double right now so that if it is a floating point number, it will maintain the decimal but if it isn't I was hoping to cut it off. I can easily accomplish what I need by doing something along the lines of:

```
public void add(Matrix<E> info){
    if(mat2[0] instanceof Number){
        for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
            if(type == Double){
            Double tmp ((Double)info.getElement(i)).doubleValue();
            Double other = tmp + ((Double)mat2[i]).doubleValue();
            mat2[i] = (E) other;
            }
            if(type == Integer){
                //do integer instead
            }
            if(type == String){
                //do String instead
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but I am wondering if I can find a more *Generic* war of doing this without all the checks. The program is for an assignment so I must use generics. The idea is to be able to add and multiply the types in the array 'mat2'. So if I have Integer types they need to add together. If I have Strings they need to add together as well.

Comment: Whenever you find yourself checking the type like this, it often means a hack is there.  Due to type erasure, there is no type information available at runtime.  You might want to find another way of doing this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have to do it through generics unfortunately. This is for an assignment.

Comment: Tell us what things your class needs to do with the generic array/matrix?  For example, maybe you want to add items, maybe you want to sum things.